# Configuring the Hue SDK in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, build, philips-hue

I'm trying to use the Hue SDK for iOS (iOS deployment target: 9.3) in swift. I've downloaded [the source from github](https://github.com/PhilipsHue/PhilipsHueSDK-iOS-OSX) and followed the instructions..

1. Created a new iOS application in Xcode (Version 7.3.1)
2. Dragged the framework (HueSDK_iOS.framework) into the project
3. Dragged the "Lumberjack" folder into the project, made sure that the target was selected and the "copy if needed"-option was selected
4. Creted a bridging-header, using a dummy-objC-file, and added "#import "
5. Added "-ObjC" to the linker flags in the targets build settings:
   [image: linker flags]
6. Added `let sdk = PHHueSDK()` in AppDelegate

The have performed "clean build folder"
When I run the App, I get the following error messages:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_DDLog",
>   referenced from:
>
> ```
>   objc-class-ref in HueSDK_iOS(PHBridgeVersionManager.o)
>   objc-class-ref in HueSDK_iOS(PHAuthentication.o)
>   objc-class-ref in HueSDK_iOS(PHHeartbeatProcessingLocal.o)
>   objc-class-ref in HueSDK_iOS(PHCLIPWrapper.o)
>   objc-class-ref in HueSDK_iOS(PHAuthenticationStorage.o)
>   objc-class-ref in HueSDK_iOS(PHHueSDK.o)
>   objc-class-ref in HueSDK_iOS(PHHttpRequester.o)
>   ...
> ```
>
> "_OBJC_CLASS_$_DDTTYLogger", referenced from:
>
> ```
>   objc-class-ref in HueSDK_iOS(PHHueSDK.o)
> ```
>
> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
>
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit
>
> code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

It seems that i have a problem linking the SDK to the project.

**What am I doing wrong?**

My problem seems to be related to this [stack overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24099901/get-phillips-hue-framework-sdk-running-with-swift). 
I have also added the SystemConfiguration.framework suggested in that thread, but without success.

Answer (score 0):

DDLog is a Lumberjack method, so the linker is not finding the compiled Lumberjack code.

@Rapsefar, I followed the steps exactly as you outlined above using 7.3.1, 9.3, and the current HueSDK_iOS.framework and Lumberjack folder to create an app named "HueSwiftiOS". It compiled and ran without problem. Here is the content of my bridging header file:

```
//  HueSwiftiOS-Bridging-Header.h
#ifndef HueSwiftiOS_Bridging_Header_h
#define HueSwiftiOS_Bridging_Header_h
#import <HueSDK_iOS/HueSDK.h>
#endif
```

No linker errors and the call:

```
let sdk = PHHueSDK()
print("sdk initialized: \(sdk)")
```

reports:

```
sdk initialized: <PHHueSDK: 0x125645640>
```

[image: Project Layout]

[image: Target Build Settings]

Comment: Yeah, I see, but I don't know why it isn't finding it.. I have followed the guide and double and triple checked all the places I think it should be set.. What could I be missing?

Comment: @Rapsefar, I edited the answer above with more detail.

Comment: Thank you very much for your try, I just retried without any luck, still the same 3 errors. Maybe the problem occurs because I also have Xcode 8 - beta installed, eventhough i thought they would be completely seperated..

Comment: I've just in Xcode 8 (Version 8.0 beta 2), with the exact same result.

Comment: @Repsefar, at this point, I have only two suggestions. 1) Delete your project and try again from scratch -- sometimes that actually works. or 2) If there is someway to get it to you, I could zip up my working project and send it to you.